# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, anaconda, tensorflow

Пытаюсь запустить подготовить изображения для нейронки

Использую следующий data.py ([github](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/data.py))

Но при компиляции пишет следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто знает как поправить, т.к. с Pythonом не очень дружен, больше по Java :3

Спасибо!

*P.S. I have Python 3.6.6 x64 (Anaconda For Windows)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
total = len(images) / 2
```

на (целочисленное деление):

```
total = len(images) // 2
```

Comment: Чувак, да ты волшебник
Спасибо!